# How to stake a smart contract's money?

Tags: smart-contract, staking, haskell

Is it possible to delegate the money locked in a smart contract? And how? Using what haskell instructions?

Comment: Please rephrase into a toplevel question.

Comment: @daedalusdaemon sorry but what is a toplevel question?

Comment: I meant the Title question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shelley address has two parts: payment part and staking part. For each of these parts, you have its specific private key and whoever holds it, has the ability to manage that part. So, you have an address where the payment part if managed by the smart contact, but the staking part is managed by you. This video might be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjPf_b9UQNs

So, a Shelley payment addresses that is used by scripts can still delegate to an associated stake key. When you create the locked output, you decide the staking.

Comment: Can you share some documentation or examples of what this might look like?

Comment: I think a good documentation for how addresses are working is https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0019/CIP-0019.md. Basically, as an example, you make a payment address that is used in the contract script, but where the payment address uses your stake address, so you own the stake rights.

Comment: What do you mean by a "shelley payment address that use scripts"?

Comment: Sorry, that is typo, a payment address used by scripts.

Comment: @MarekMahut-StakeNuts So just to clarify, you mean any address used by a smart-contract? Because, you know, I could write a script on my laptop that uses my address and obviously I can do whatever I want with this address. Or did you mean something more precise?

Comment: A shelley address has two parts: payment part and staking part. For each of these parts, you have its specific private key and whoever holds it, has the ability to manage that part. So, you have an address where the payment part if managed by the smart contact, but the staking part is managed by you. This video might be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjPf_b9UQNs

Comment: @MarekMahut-StakeNuts: I edited your answer to add this comment.